# Check which permissionsets makes a field read-only or editable

Tags: soql, permission-sets, field-level-security

I have a field for eg: testField__c on some object testObject__c.I have given the features of editable or readonly to this field based on permissionsets.Now I have to check,which permissionsets has made this field editable /readonly through SOQL.

Query tried :

```
SELECT parentid,SobjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE SobjectType = 'testObject__c' and field = 'testField__c'
```

Returning 0 rows.

Comment: Found the answer.I have to give field ="testObject__c.testField__c' to query the same.I am able to query it now

Comment: Sounds good that you have found the answer.Add this as an answer when you are able to, to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Soql query's where clause has some error in it.

Updated query:

```
SELECT parentid,SobjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE SobjectType = 'testObject__c' and field = 'testObject__c.testField__c'
```

This will fetch all the permissionsets and profiles for which the field is given readonly or edit access in the org.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the name of permission set through Reference field `Parent`. Following query could be helpful.You can apply where clause as you needed.

```
Select Parent.name,field From FieldPermissions where parent.name='TempPermissionSet' and SobjectType ='User'
```

Comment: There are lots of permission sets and i dont know which permissionsets has this field editable or readonly.